# How to show error page for auth failure in apache httpd basic authentication

Tags: apache, authentication

I want to show an error page for basic auth in apache, if it fails authentication.

currently it is prompting for username and password again and again until we hit cancel or using correct credentials.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
            AuthType basic
            AuthName "Restricted"
            AuthBasicProvider file
            AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/pass
            Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Here, i need to customize that if user enters invalid credentials for say 3 times, it should by default throw error page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ErrorDocument directive

```
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/error_unauthorized.html
```

However, this happens when someone gives up and presses cancel, not when they fail to auth a certain number of times. So, the short answer is, no you can't do that.

The longer answer is that if you use some other form of auth (such as form-based, cookie auth, like most sites use these days), then you have much more control over failure states. But of course you'd have to code the handlers on the server side to make that happen.